# Docker: cant access env variables inside pm2 nodejs code

Tags: node.js, docker, shell, environment-variables, pm2

So I am facing a weird problem. I am starting a docker container with a entrypoint file and a env variable `edgeboxId`. The entrypoint.sh contains some pm2 commands to start my nodejs application.

Entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -u deploy bash << EOF
cd /home/deploy/ce-edgebox-agent
pm2 start ecosystem.json
EOF
echo "out of the deploy user"

echo Entering Entryopint file
echo "export edgeboxId=$edgeboxId">> /etc/bash.bashrc

sudo -u edgebox bash << EOF
pm2 start ce-edgebox-application --update-env 
EOF
echo "out of application user"
sleep infinity
```

Inside dockerfile, I am using following line to import entrypoint.sh file.

```
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "./entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Then i enter inside container using:

```
docker exec -it <containerId> bash
```

**Expectation**:

I expect `edgeboxId` accessible inside nodejs application running inside pm2 process as soon as the the container starts with my entrypoint.sh file.

**Whats really happening:**

`edgeboxId` appears undefined inside nodejs application but when i run the command `pm2 restart ce-edgebox-application --update-env` manually inside container then `edgeboxId` is accessible inside nodejs application.

**Question:**
How to make `edgeboxId` accessible inside nodejs as soon as the container starts with my entrypoint.sh file?

Comment: Most paths in Docker don't actually read shell dotfiles and frequently don't run GNU bash, so writing a variable to `/etc/bash.bashrc` will be ineffective.  You also don't usually need `sudo` or `pm2` in Docker, since a container can specify its own user ID and manage the main process's lifecycle.  How are you starting the container; what sets the `$edgeboxId` variable so that this script can read it?

Comment: 1. We are starting container using aws ecs task and passing the env variable there. This script can read that env variable.
2. I think writing in `/etc/bash.bashrc` is effective because i can do `echo $edgeboxId` in both root and edgebox user and get the value. But Somehow the nodejs code running as pm2 process is not able to access it until i manually type the command inside container: `pm2 restart ce-edgebox-application --update-env`
3. pm2 is required in our case due to the way our system is designed.

Comment: @DavidMaze I believe this a problem of shell but cannot pinpoint how and where.

Comment: If you get rid of all of this – no `pm2`, no `sudo`, no wrapper script, no `docker exec` – and just set the image's `CMD ["node", "myscript.js"]`, does it work?

Comment: (One possible problem is that `sudo` resets the environment to a small set of known-safe variables.  But, again, you pretty much never need `sudo` in Docker, since you can set the image to run with any `USER` you want, or `docker run -u` the container with an arbitrary user.)

Comment: @DavidMaze you are right about running the image as any user. but in my case it is not possible, i guess because I need to switch to 2 different users. I didnt put my complete entrypoint.sh file in the question but now I am updating the question to show complete entrypoint.sh file

Comment: ...that sounds like you need two single-process containers.  They can use the same image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241575/discussion-between-anudocs-and-david-maze).